# *ngFor no code completion for item in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

I'm not sure if this is a problem or if I should not expect it to work but when I use `*ngForm` as shown below I can not get code completion for employee. In other words, the IDE doesn't seem to know that employee is of type `Employee` although it does recognize employees from 'assetsComponent public var employees:Employee[]'

```
<div>All Employess</div>
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{ employee.firstName }} {{employee.lastName}}</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using:

```
Angular JS Version: 163.6110.28
WebStorm 2016.3 EAP
```

Comment: I think this might belong more on the JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a WebStorm issue; please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23754 to be notified on any progress with it